# Codeigniter get not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

This in the controller ajax

```
function get_class_posts()
{
echo json_encode($this->input->get());
}
```

Straight from the console line in chrome:

`$.get("/ajax/get_class_posts",{user_id:2},function(data){window.vv = data})`

`RESPONSE >> OBJECT`

`window.vv`

`RESPONSE >> "{"\/ajax\/get_class_posts":""}"`

when I do `$.post(...)` and `$this->input->post()` it works as it should (i.e. returns `user_id:2`)

Comment: What is `$this->input` ?

Comment: the input class in codeigniter. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html

Comment: Try for a test: `echo json_encode($_GET);`

Comment: it returns `"{"\/ajax\/get_class_posts":""}"` even though i passed the data user_id:2.. according to chrome dev's network tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you allowed the GET array to pass in Codeigniter. In your config/config.php make sure you have ...

$config['allow_get_array']      = TRUE;

Otherwise you will not have the GET variables.